# Alembic shows "empty message" when running upgrade

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

When I run an Alembic upgrade I see "empty message" next to the revision number instead of "users table". I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database).

What should appear according to the author:

```
(venv) $ flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> e517276bb1c2, users table
```

What appeared for me:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\HP\microblog> flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 907246db53d3, empty message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a message when creating the revision, so it shows a default, "empty message". Provide a message with the `-m` option as shown in the tutorial.

```
(venv) $ flask db migrate -m "users table"
```

---

If you're using Flask-Alembic instead of Flask-Migrate, the message is a required argument so this doesn't happen.

```
(venv) $ flask db revision "users table"
```